# R: Convert large list to data frame

Tags: r, database, list

I have a large list (of 10 elements) called `res` as shown below. Please, notice that I only show 3 of the elements so the post isn't too long.

```
> str(res)
List of 10
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..$ id               : chr "121040004071"
  ..$ province         : chr "Castellón/Castelló"
  ..$ comunidadAutonoma: chr "Comunitat Valenciana"
  ..$ muni             : chr "Segorbe"
  ..$ type             : chr "portal"
  ..$ address          : chr "A-23"
  ..$ geom             : chr "POINT(-0.428888910999945 39.806487449)"
  ..$ lat              : num 39.8
  ..$ lng              : num -0.429
  ..$ portalNumber     : chr "23"
  ..$ stateMsg         : chr "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda"
  ..$ state            : chr "1"
  ..$ countryCode      : chr "011"
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..$ id               : chr "121040004071"
  ..$ province         : chr "Castellón/Castelló"
  ..$ comunidadAutonoma: chr "Comunitat Valenciana"
  ..$ muni             : chr "Segorbe"
  ..$ type             : chr "portal"
  ..$ address          : chr "A-23"
  ..$ geom             : chr "POINT(-0.428888910999945 39.806487449)"
  ..$ lat              : num 39.8
  ..$ lng              : num -0.429
  ..$ portalNumber     : chr "23"
  ..$ stateMsg         : chr "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda"
  ..$ state            : chr "1"
  ..$ countryCode      : chr "011"
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..$ id               : chr "121040004071"
  ..$ province         : chr "Castellón/Castelló"
  ..$ comunidadAutonoma: chr "Comunitat Valenciana"
  ..$ muni             : chr "Segorbe"
  ..$ type             : chr "portal"
  ..$ address          : chr "A-23"
  ..$ geom             : chr "POINT(-0.428888910999945 39.806487449)"
  ..$ lat              : num 39.8
  ..$ lng              : num -0.429
  ..$ portalNumber     : chr "23"
  ..$ stateMsg         : chr "Resultado exacto de la búsqueda"
  ..$ state            : chr "1"
  ..$ countryCode      : chr "011"
```

Each observation corresponds to a certain address in the city of Valencia, Spain. After geocoding my 10 addresses, I ended up with 13 variables for each address containing information about longitude, latitude, province, etc.

I would like to make it a data frame so that for every row we have the main `$:'data.frame` and the rest of `..$ x` are the variables/columns.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could try `dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = 'data.frame')`

Comment: Does `rbindlist(res)` work for you? This function is available in `data.table` library

Comment: Thanks to both!  I tried both `dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = 'data.frame')` and `rbindlist(res)` and they worked perfectly.

Comment: I came up with other question about this. Unlike the example above, that all of addresses have 13 variables,  now, I happen to have a longer list (around 300 elements),  and some of them do not have the same number of variables.

Comment: Take a look to `merge` function

Answer (score 0):

You can ouse the following functions:

`Map` function

```
list_data <- Map(as.data.frame, list_data)
```

`rbindlist` function

```
datarbind <- rbindlist(list_data)
```

Comment: you are welcome, please do not forget to vote for my answer if it worked ;)

Comment: don't forget the `library(data.table)` for the second answer

Comment: Sure!  I need at least 15 in reputation to vote, but it says that my feedback was recorded